# If I change the cable of a USB device, will the drivers/descriptors be affected?

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-failure

I swapped out the USB cable for a controller I was fixing (because the 5V wire broke) and now any PC I use it on can't recognize it. Could me changing the wire of broken it?

Comment: If you don't solder it right...

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The cable is literally just wire, and any drivers/descriptors are on the controller chip on the device.

Chances are something went wrong with the fix